# Grails OSGi plugin instsallation error

Tags: grails, osgi, grails-plugin

I'm trying to install the Grails OSGi plugin into a new Grails 2.0.3 app.

```
> grails create-app sandbox
| Created Grails Application at /home/pocon64/sandbox

> cd sandbox

> grails install-plugin osgi
| Plugin installed.

> grails run-war
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Error WARNING: Dependencies cannot be resolved for plugin [osgi] due to error: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings(groovy.util.ConfigObject) (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings(groovy.util.ConfigObject)
    at dependencies$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(dependencies.groovy:45)
    at dependencies$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(dependencies.groovy)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at dependencies$_run_closure1.doCall(dependencies.groovy:28)
    at dependencies$_run_closure1.doCall(dependencies.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_pluginDependencyHandler_closure11.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:1278)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_pluginDependencyHandler_closure11.call(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1219)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$configureDependencyManager.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1102)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:999)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:982)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:959)
| Error WARNING: Dependencies cannot be resolved for plugin [osgi] due to error: Cannot cast object '{}' with class 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to class 'org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ResolverSettings(groovy.util.ConfigObject)
| Compiling 42 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Compile error during compilation with javac.
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:3: package org.osgi.framework does not exist
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
                         ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:4: package org.osgi.framework does not exist
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
                         ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:8: package org.springframework.osgi.context does not exist
import org.springframework.osgi.context.ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext;
                                       ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol: class ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext
    GrailsWebApplicationContext implements ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext {
                                           ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BundleContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
    private BundleContext bundleContext = null;
            ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Bundle
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
    public Bundle getBundle() {
           ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BundleContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
    public BundleContext getBundleContext() {
           ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:71: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BundleContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
    public void setBundleContext(BundleContext context) {
                                 ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:42: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
    if (parent instanceof ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext) {
                          ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:43: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
        ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext osgiParent = (ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext) parent;
        ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:43: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
        ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext osgiParent = (ConfigurableOsgiBundleApplicationContext) parent;
                                                               ^
/home/pocon64/.grails/2.0.3/projects/sandbox/plugins/osgi-0.2.1/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class BundleContext
location: class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsOsgiWebApplicationContext
                    BundleContext context = osgiParent.getBundleContext();
                    ^
12 errors


1 error
```

It seems that everything is OK until I try to build the war. I don't understand which dependency is missing, or why? I may be missing something simple, as I'm quite new to Grails, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Try uncommenting the following in your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
mavenCentral()
```

And retry.